# Emgu CV data structure usage

Tags: emgucv

When using EmguCV for image processing, 
Is it recommended to only work with the Image object or do some people work with Matrix and Mat objects?

It seems very cumbersone to convert from one to the other, moreover, some functions such ad ConnectedComponents do not  seem to work correctly (or maybe bad usage of these data types although everything compiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think after EMGU version 3.0, you are encouraged to use the Mat or UMat classes. With version 3.0 EMGU switched from using the OpenCV C interface to C++. But `Image<,>`, `Mat` and `UMat` all implements the `IInputArray` so they can all be used in many of the `CvInvoke` methods.

You can read a little bit about it in the last section of their [tutorial](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial#Upgrading_from_Emgu_CV_2.x_to_3.x), which also highlights the benefits of using `UMat`, as it allows the image processing methods to be processed on a GPU.